# How to add custom option price when product is adding add to cart using controller

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options, addtocart, controllers

I have to add the custom option price when product is adding add to cart using controller

Answer (score 0):

If you have a product with custom options like this -

[image]

and you want to add it to cart with the option Zip Type = Metal, use the following code:

```
    <?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class AddToCart
{
    private $cart;
    private $productRepository;
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ){
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


    protected function _initProduct($productId)
    {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        try {
            return $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public function addToCart()
    {
        $product = $this->_initProduct("8");
        $this->cart->addProduct($product, ['options' => [1 => 2]] );
        $this->cart->save();
    }
}
```